# What is this syntax in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, wcf

The following is from a WCF sample I am working on.

```
<ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode:=InstanceContextMode.Single)> _
<Foobar()> _
Public Class Service1
```

I've never understood this and just used examples, but I would like to understand what is going on here.  What exactly is the stuff inside the <> brackets?  How are these related to Service1?  I understand the ServiceBehavior is related to the hosting, but what about Foobar?

Comment: It's an attribute mostly of interest to some API/Framework that can query it's functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are [Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx#Y342). The ServiceBehaviourAttribute is defined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.aspx) and Foobar is a custom attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The bits inside the `<>` are [attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute.aspx). You can write custom attributes as required which is what `FooBar` is.

In the case of [ServiceBehaviour](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.aspx), the [InstanceContextMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.instancecontextmode.aspx) property specifies whether and when services and their service objects are to be recycled during an exchange with a client. Details are in the link above.